# connecting a raspberry pi to a fedora and a windows 7 machine

Tags: java, distributed-computing, raspberry-pi

I am not sure where i would post this question, so please do not delete this question and just guide me to where i can post this question.

My question is that by buying a switch would I be able to connect two raspberry pi's a fedora desktop and a windows 7 laptop together.

What setting do I need to consider, what software do i need etc.

Thanks

Comment: Not entirely sure I follow the question but just my two cents: Software: Synergy

Comment: you can connect them with twine. twine does not support many features, but then again you did not specify what you need.

Comment: We won't delete the question if it abides to the guidelines in the [faq], this doesn't.....

Comment: Also what exactly does this have to do with CSS???

Comment: First you need to figure out exactly what "connect" means. Do you want RS-232? I2C? TCP/IP?